# Why is ID is not defined POSTing to Sharepoint 2013 list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, ajax, json

My script:
 I have got a list that I want to populate with a HTML form. I'm using the following but I keep getting ID is not defined in google debugger.

```
<script>
    $('#submitdata').click(function(){

    var itemProperties = {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.ChangeOfAddressListListItem" },
        Title: $("#firstName").val(),
        PerOrBus: "True"

    };



    $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items(" + id + ")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

It is definitely connected to the list alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used "id" variable in your code, but where did you define/assign it.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items(" + id + ")
```

Comment: Should I put it in the metadata?

Comment: id is auto generated on the list side, so I thought I wouldn't need it

Comment: id is auto generated when you are creating a new item. For this request form your REST API url without mentioning the ID.
`url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items` 

 However if you want edit an existing item you need to pass the corresponding List Item ID.
`url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items(" + id + ")`

Comment: ah yes, that is how I had it originally and it didn't work that way either.

Comment: If you are trying to create a new list item then remove "IF-MATCH" and "X-HTTP-METHOD" entries from your request headers. 
`headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        }`